# Undo Redo using PostSharp for Nested property or collections

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, postsharp, undo-redo

I am in midway implementing an UndoRedo container for a view model that contains nested properties and ObservableCollection. I am using PostSharp for Exception Handling in the application and thought of reusing it for implementing an undo-redo engine as stated in the article:
http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/undoredo

Although the above article is for windowsForms which had binding limitations, I have made the engine to adopt the rich binding wpf platform and it is working nice for single properties.

I am wondering how to extend the UndoableAttribute to take care of Nested properties and collections. My tries and googling skills have proved futile till now. Any idea, or pointer to some article would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are after. Providing undo functionality on object graphs can be quite complicated task. You would have to state more specifically what you want to achieve.

Generally you could instrument all nested objects and write some specialized collections to store all changes in some kind of global container.

We are working on providing such a functionality as part of future release of PostSharp.Patterns libraries – it should make to 3.1 or 3.2.

Comment: thenks for the reply. I have a ViewModel that a list of entities that caters to UI needs. I ant the undo redo to take care if any entity is getting added or removed from the collection. Can you guide?